Change base input tag language in react app, overwrite base browser dependent language
I have a React TS app. There I have i18n. Unfortunatelly the base language of the input with date type depends on the browser settings and independent from the langauge selection inside the app.
It is also independent from the lang property.
If English is selected in the browser then it looks like this:

But if German is the selected one, than it shows:

I have found many question about the topic, but there were no usable responses.
So is it possible to change this text from my React app based on the selected language?
Thanks in advance.

HTML [ input type="date" ] tag is influenced by the browser and its localization depends on the user's browser settings.
To have full control over the date format and localization, use a custom date picker component.
Install react-datepicker and date-fns
npm install react-datepicker date-fns

then import and fix the code
here is the code
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
import { registerLocale, setDefaultLocale } from 'react-datepicker';
import en from 'date-fns/locale/en-US';
import de from 'date-fns/locale/de';


registerLocale('en', en);
registerLocale('de', de);

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState<Date | null>(new Date());
  const [locale, setLocale] = useState<string>('en'); // Default to English

  
  const handleLanguageChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setLocale(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={handleLanguageChange}>
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="de">German</option>
      </select>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date: Date | null) => setStartDate(date)}
        locale={locale}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

